# How to keep 2 versions of source code in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm new to TFS and I need to have a new "copy" of the source code in order to make some fixes/add new features that will later be tested and decided if the feature/fix will be commited to the main copy of the source control.

I want this main copy to be used as the source code that will be compiled and deployed to the production server, and this new copy will be for this end.

Later if the changes are approved by the client, I want to commit them to the main copy to have them deployed to the production server.

I'm pretty sure there is a feature in TFS that will do it easily, but I need some help.

Comment: [See the MSDN documentation on TFS branching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181423.aspx) - the branches represent the "copies". Then it's just a matter of using an appropriate workflow to merge changesets (or branches) between the 'prod' and 'staging' and 'dev/features'. TFS is only 'easy' on the surface and, if using TFS-GIT is an option I'd urge simultaneous exploration of that - *especially* when wishing to do semi-independent feature development.

Comment: @user2864740 I disagree with your statement. I have seen messes with both models. Git is not necessarily easier then TFVC or any other centralized version control; it all depends on the context. Organizational boundaries, know-how, experience, processes play a huge role on making any version control system effective.

Comment: @GiulioVian It has nothing to with centralized vs not-centralized. It has everything to do with branching.

Comment: You should try and avoid branching at all costs as it introduces complicity that results in poor code quality and bugs in production. You should use feature toggles and other engineering to reduce the need to branch as much as posible. in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect this to be quick and without a lot of changes, you may be talking about a shelveset.  You make changes in your local copy and save them as a "shelveset".  When you want to build without them, get latest and build.  When you want to build with them, you get latest, unshelve your changes locally and build.  When you're ready to check them in, unshelve them and check them in.

If this is going to take some time, a branch might be a better bet. When you're done with your edit/test cycle, you merge the changes back to your main branch and check them in.

Comment: branch seems to be a better solution for me, is this ok to have around 10 branches? one for each fix/feature as they are not related to each one and there will be more people working on them...

Comment: The number of branches shouldn't be a problem in itself, but if they're all working in the same module later merges might get messy.  If the branches stay open for a long time, keeping all the other bits current in the branches takes time.  Name the branches clearly and you should be fine.

Comment: @user3900456 TFS branching *is* messy when doing semi-independent feature development, or using a branch-per feature (ie. not a epic; and branch-per bugfix is simply unmaintainable!), which is why I recommend looking at using TFS's Git support (which is a much better 'real world development' model, IMOHO). While shelvesets are handy for work-in-progress or local changes I do not find that they are part of a long-term workflow process, especially when things start to get .. involved.

Answer (score 3):

There is no clear cut answer as you must consider the entire process, especially how much you are freezing a version of the code, how do you enhance the new codebase etc.
I wholeheartedly suggest to *study* [ALM Rangers' Version control guidance](http://aka.ms/treasure18), because it distills the experience of many different people and customer scenarios (much more than the sheer number of authors, trust me). After that, implement the chosen strategy and follow it by the book.